# Unable to increment by one a defined variable

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Modificador_BD_EQUIPOS_Y_HERRAMIENTAS()

    Dim titulo_codigoFila As String
    Dim titulo_operacion As String
    Dim mensaje_codigoFila As String
    Dim mensaje_operacion As String
    Dim codigoFila As Integer
    Dim modificacion As String


titulo_codigoFila = "Modificar Ítem"
mensaje_codigoFila = "Por favor, introduce el código del ítem"
codigoFila = InputBox(mensaje_codigoFila, titulo_codigoFila)
'Gathers the code of the item, which is just the row the item's on

columnaBase = 3
Set celdaCategoria = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, columnaBase)
Set celdaInterseccion = ActiveSheet.Cells(codigoFila, columnaBase)
'defines the category cell, and the intersection cell, which is just the coordinates of the items data

'Do While celdaInterseccion.Value <> "" -- I COMMENTED OUT THE WHILE LOOP SO I WONT CRASH EXCEL
    titulo_operacion = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(celdaCategoria.Value) + " del Ítem"
    mensaje_operacion = "Introduce la información del campo " + UCase(celdaCategoria.Value) + ". El valor que deseas modificar es: " + celdaInterseccion.Value
    modificacion = InputBox(mensaje_operacion, titulo_operacion)
'shows an inputbox with info taken from the category cell and the item's current data for the category

    If Not modificacion = "" Then
    celdaInterseccion.Value = modificacion
    End If
'if the input is not an empty string, it overwrites the item's data

    columnaBase = columnaBase + 1
'the problem is HERE - it doesnt seem to add 1 back to columnaBase

'Loop
    whatever = celdaCategoria.Value
    MsgBox (whatever)
'made this last part so as to confirm if it adds 1 to columnaBase's value

End Sub
```

This is the code i've written for modifying the data of items in a database. The database is super simple; a list of items with certain info about them in the columns to the right, with the name of the category of the data atop every column (eg. listed below the "date" column are the dates on which certain things were bought).

The categories are all in located in row Nº 2, and go from column B to whenever the categories end. What my code is intended to do is to, parting from a predefined column (in absolute value), edit an item's data, category by category. It does it great the with the first column, but when i add 1 to the predefined column value, somehow it doesn't happen, and it's forever stuck on the column you start with.

I have absolutely no idea as to why on earth it doesn't work. Notice i commented out the While Loop; crashed Excel a couple of times trying to fix this... just a couple :)

Comment: The problem is that you do nothing with the `columnaBase` variable (except incrementing it) inside the loop, so it's unclear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were working with a *Cell Object* `celdaInterseccion` that you define before you loop, even if you increase `ColumnaBase` during your loop, you didn't affect the object `celdaInterseccion` with that change.

Ergo your test to stop the loop will always be the same and you'll be stuck in that loop forever.

So you just need to add `Set celdaInterseccion = ActiveSheet.Cells(codigoFila, columnaBase)` at the end of the loop to update the *Cell Object* and change the cell that is tested.

Here is your code with the correction :

```
Sub Modificador_BD_EQUIPOS_Y_HERRAMIENTAS()

    Dim titulo_codigoFila As String
    Dim titulo_operacion As String
    Dim mensaje_codigoFila As String
    Dim mensaje_operacion As String
    Dim codigoFila As Integer
    Dim modificacion As String


titulo_codigoFila = "Modificar Ítem"
mensaje_codigoFila = "Por favor, introduce el código del ítem"
'Gathers the code of the item, which is just the row the item's on
codigoFila = InputBox(mensaje_codigoFila, titulo_codigoFila)

columnaBase = 3
'defines the category cell, and the intersection cell, which is just the coordinates of the items data
Set celdaCategoria = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, columnaBase)
Set celdaInterseccion = ActiveSheet.Cells(codigoFila, columnaBase)

Do While celdaCategoria.Value <> "" '-- I COMMENTED OUT THE WHILE LOOP SO I WONT CRASH EXCEL
    titulo_operacion = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(celdaCategoria.Value) & " del Ítem"
    mensaje_operacion = "Introduce la información del campo " + UCase(celdaCategoria.Value) & ". El valor que deseas modificar es: " & celdaInterseccion.Value
    'shows an inputbox with info taken from the category cell and the item's current data for the category
    modificacion = InputBox(mensaje_operacion, titulo_operacion)

    If modificacion <> "" Then
        'if the input is not an empty string, it overwrites the item's data
        celdaInterseccion.Value = modificacion
    End If

    columnaBase = columnaBase + 1
    'the problem WAS here :
    'you need to reSet the Cell Object that you are working with to continue looping properly
    Set celdaCategoria = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, columnaBase)
    Set celdaInterseccion = ActiveSheet.Cells(codigoFila, columnaBase)

    'made this last part so as to confirm if it adds 1 to columnaBase's value
    'Uncomment to check that it is working
    'MsgBox celdaCategoria.Value
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Well, actually the While Loop has to use celdaCategoria, because I need the loop to stop when the catogories "**end**" (category cell is an empty string), not when the data is an empty string. However, I didn't know that I had to "set again" (reset) the cell object; like I said, i assumed it would update automatically. Again, thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad I could help! If you want the code to stop when the category is empty, change `Do While celdaInterseccion.Value <> ""` to `Do While celdaCategoria.Value <> ""` (look at the edit). Now, you should be able to upvote the post that you find useful, so welcome to SO! ;)

Answer (score 1):

you don't seem to define     columnaBase    anywhere.

So just add

```
Dim columnaBase As Integer
```

to the beginning, where you add you variables.

Comment: None, it just doesnt go forward on the columns! (columnaBase is the base column value)

Comment: You set celdaCategoria once. But you never seem to update, so I don't really understand your part where you want to confirm if the value of columnaBase is increased by 1

Comment: how do I update celdaCategoria (or a range object anyways)? I assumed that by changing the base column value celdaCategorias´ address would change automatically... I added the confirmation part as a sort of hardcoded debugging to see if celdaCategorias' position was actually changing.

Comment: you have to add 
Set celdaCategoria = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, columnaBase)
Set celdaInterseccion = ActiveSheet.Cells(codigoFila, columnaBase)
after you incremented your columnaBase value.

Answer (score 1):

To really test the Msgbox output is correct you need to add the lines

```
Set celdaCategoria = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, columnaBase)
Set celdaInterseccion = ActiveSheet.Cells(codigoFila, columnaBase)
```

before the lines

```
whatever = celdaCategoria.Value
MsgBox (whatever)
```

to really test if the +1 works

Comment: But you set the range *before* the loop - you need to do it **inside** the loop!

Comment: Shouldn't it work anyways? For instance, if i run the code like it wrote it here (no While Loop), it doesn't advance the columns either.

Comment: How would it if you aren't looping?Changing the value of an integer variable will not affect the `Range` object you set - you have to reset it using the new column number.

Comment: It's because you **only Set once** the Cell Object that you are working with, and it won't be affected by external change **unless you set it again**. See my answer for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
 columnaBase = columnaBase + 1       '<~~ add 1 to columnaBase
'the problem is HERE - it doesnt seem to add 1 back to columnaBase

'Loop
    whatever = celdaCategoria.Value  '<~~ read value of celdaCategora
```

The problem is that `celdaCategoria` has been set before you incremented `columnaBase`. These two variables are completely independent of each other.

If you want to see the effect of the increment, then you will need to update the Range object set to `celdaCategoria` with the new `columnaBase` value:

---

```
columnaBase = columnaBase + 1

Set celdaCategoria = Cells(2, columnaBase)
whatever = celdaCategoria.Value
```

---

Which should output the correct value.